# Как установить MySQL 8.0 (8.0.15+) на Ubuntu 18.04 [так же для DigitalOcean]

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, digitalocean

У меня возникла проблема: Который раз пытаюсь установить MySQL на Ububtu-server (18.04) и постоянно какие-то ошибки. Подскажите пожалуйста пошаговую установку. А так же как дистанцинно подключаться к MySQL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Данный вариант 3 раза прогонялся на серверах DigitalOcean и OVH.
*В случае, если есть у вас примечания/дополнения - пишите об этом в комментарии.*

Инструкция по установке **MySQL 8.0.15+** на **Ubuntu 18.04**:

## Удаление MySQL (если накосячили)

Если вы уже пытались установить MySQL и где-то у вас произошла ошибка, то скопируйте вот эти строки и вставьте их в командную строку Ubuntu, чтобы начать весь процесс заного:

```
sudo -i
service mysql stop
killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
apt-get --yes purge mysql-server mysql-client
apt-get --yes autoremove --purge
apt-get autoclean
deluser --remove-home mysql
delgroup mysql
rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql /etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql* /var/log/upstart/mysql.log* /var/run/mysqld
updatedb
exit
```

## Начало установки MySQL

1. Вводим команду, которая загружает списки пакетов из репозиториев и «обновляет» их, чтобы получить информацию о новейших версиях пакетов и их зависимостях.

```
sudo apt update
```

2. Вводим команду, которая извлечет новые версии пакетов, существующих на компьютере:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

3. Скачиваем файл с помощью wget:

```
wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb
```

4. Чтобы проверить, что файл скачался:

```
ls
```

Файл будет называться **mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb**

5. Запускаем распаковку и установку файла:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config*
```

6. У нас появится окно, в котором надо лишь проверить, что стоит **MySQL Server & Cluster (Currently selected: mysql-8.0)**. В случае, если стоит **5.*** версия, то нажмите Enter по данной строке и выберите 8.0.

Если все верно - выбирает `Ok` в самом низу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

7. Дальше часто вылезает ошибка:

```
Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst
maintainerscript of the package mysql-apt-config)
```

Это нормально. Дальше узнаете почему это так происходит.

[image: введите сюда]

8. Вводим команду:

```
apt update
```

У нас выводится ошибка о том, что у ключа (В основном это ключ **8C718D3B5072E1F5**) истек срок службы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

9. Чтобы решить проблему с ключем пишем следующую строчку:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 8C718D3B5072E1F5
```

Если у вас ключ в Пункте 8 другой - замените концовку на Ваш ключ.

10. Дальше вводим следующие команды:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Возможно этого появится наше окошко из пункта 6 два раза, где мы просто жмем `Ok` 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И может появиться вот такое окошко, где мы просто жмем `Keep the local version currently installed`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

11. Устанавливаем **MySQL server**:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

12. Должно открыться окно, где мы должны ввести пароль новый Администратора (**root**) для MySQL (пароль от Ubuntu и от MySQL могут быть разные):
    [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
13. Далее просто жмем `Ok`
14. В окне, где будет рассказываться про новую аутификацию MySQL 8 - жмем `**Use Strong Password Encryption (Recommended)**`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

15. После того как розовые окошки закончились, вводим следующую команду:

```
 mysql_secure_installation
```

Вводим наш пароль для MySQL.

Дальше на вопросы **лично я** ответил следующим образом:

```
Validate pass - N
Change pass for root - n
Anonym users - y
Remote root access - y
Test tables - y
Reload privilige - y
```

## Финальная часть

1. Вводим команду для проверки, что MySQL работает:

```
systemctl status mysql
```

2. Вводим команду, чтобы проверить, что **MySQL 8.0** установлен, а не **MySQL5.***:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p version
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Зайти в MySQL:

1. Просто вводим:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

## Дополнительно(Дистанционное подключение к MySQL):

1. Заходим в MySQL:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

2. Создаем нового юзера.:

```
CREATE USER `username`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY `password`;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO `user`@`%`;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

`%` - этот пользователь может подключаться как дистанционно, так и локально;
`localhost` - этот пользователь может только локально подключаться к MySQL
`* . * . * . *` - этот пользователь может подключаться только с определенного IP.

3 - Вводим команду:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Открывается окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто дописываем `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`. (чтобы с любого IP можно было подключиться)

Закрываем окно и сохраняем изменения с помощью:

```
Ctrl + X (чтобы выйти из файла)
y (чтобы подтвердить изменения)
```

Reference:
[Установка MySQL с форма DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-latest-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04)
[Удаление полностью MySQL с Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/640900/792151)